# Get maven deploy plugin artifact version at runtime in my war

Tags: java, maven, war, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

Is there anyway to get at runtime the full artifact version / build number generated by the maven deploy plugin of my war at runtime?

It'd be ok if the maven process generated and packaged up a properties file with the value.

Keep in mind that my project generates unique (timestamped) artifact versions for every deploy.

Comment: By "runtime", you mean you want to get the artifact version with code present in the WAR after the WAR is deployed to a web container, correct?

Comment: yes, that is what i mean by runtime

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries/>
            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

That will add the maven details from the pom that build the war into the MANIFEST.MF file, which you can read at runtime.

Another way that I occasionally use is to use filtering of properties files, and drop the pom values into there - useful if you already have a property file/config loading mechanism in place.

Then, when it's deployed, which uses the same values from the pom, you're fine.

-Chris

Answer (score -1):

You could package it up in your Manifest file using [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) which can be read through you application wherever you need.

Here is the basic configuration which would write the properties in pom.xml to your Manifest file.

> ```
>       <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.4</version>
>           <configuration>
>               <archive>
>                   <manifest>
>                       <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
>                   </manifest>
>                   <manifestEntries>
>                       <Implementation-Vendor>Vendor Name</Implementation-Vendor>
>                       <Implementation-Version>${revision}</Implementation-Version>
>                       <Build-Timestamp>${timestamp}</Build-Timestamp>
>                       <Build-Number>${release}_${revision}</Build-Number>
>                   </manifestEntries>
>               </archive>
>           </configuration>
>           <executions>
>           <!-- your jar executions here -->
>           </executions>           
>       </plugin>
> ```

**where your property values would be defined in pom.xml as :**

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <release>DevelopmentBuild</release>
    <revision>Some Value</revision>
<properties>
```

**EDIT:**

This can be done using [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin) also.
You can get more information on WAR Manifest Customization [Here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html).

Comment: you're missing the key point, i want the number from the deploy plugin, not something i define somewhere